# Swift 3 - how do I add clickable links to another view controller in the body of a TextView?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextview, xcode8

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2, iOS 10.

I want to do something like this.

[image]

But I cannot (despite my attempts at Googling), figure out how to create clickable links embedded in my TextView.  I suppose I could create a button and manually place it in the text so that it looks like it's part of the text but what will happen when the device is tilted landscape or on a different type of device?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have found what you need here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238366/uitextview-with-hyperlink-text
It should help you solve it :D

Comment: Thank you for a push in the right direction!

Comment: No Problem! Up vote my comment would be much appreciated!