# Swift : Expand textView URL clickable area?

Tags: ios, swift, textview, clickable

Through adding the NSLinkAttributeName to my specific word, I make a clickable textView.

Use textView callback function, I can custom my action when the specific word is tapped.

Callback is below :

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {

    delegate?.viewNeedInfoWhenURLDidTapped(linkName: URL.absoluteString)

    return false
}
```

I found that clickable area in the textView is very strange and unpredictable.

Is that possible to expand the textView clickable area ?????

Thanks, really appreciate.

Comment: This may be helpful for you https://github.com/Jitu1990/link-clickable-Label

Comment: Refer the bellow URL. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238366/uitextview-with-hyperlink-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238366/uitextview-with-hyperlink-text)

Comment: Thanks @JitendraSolanki, in some reason, I think textView is what I need.