# Textview not displaying hyperlink with default link type

Tags: ios, iphone, hyperlink, uitextview

I am using text view in tableview cell with default feature for identify  link number date address location etc.

But For text input  **googleco.in** in not working and displaying  as hyperlink.

If i am using another string like "Google.com", "Yahho.com"  is working properly in same implementation. Please  suggest default implementation of uitextview.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think it would recognize that as a link. It's not a valid URL. You can test this by adding `https://` in front of it and see if it works then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextView with hyperlink text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238366/uitextview-with-hyperlink-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NSAttributedStringKey` [.link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/key/1535719-link) to indicate that that portion of the attributed string is a link.

For example:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "googleco.in")
attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: URL(string:"https://googleco.in")!, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.lenght))
```

Comment: I m using default link feature of uitextview. Not Using Attributed string.

Comment: Probably I didn't fully express my self. I can see that you are using the link data detector and is recognizing well other strings. I believe that the UITextView's match pattern is not recognizing "googleco.in" as a URL, so I you would have to highlight your link manually.