# How to make hyperlinks in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

In Swift, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238366/uitextview-with-hyperlink-text), you can use `NSMutableAttributedString` to embed links in text.

How can I achieve this with `SwiftUI`?

I implemented it as the following, but it does not look how I want it to. [image: this].

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("By tapping Done, you agree to the ")
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("privacy policy")
            }
            Text(" and ")
            Button(action: {}) {
                Text("terms of service")
            }
            Text(" .")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI is not supporting any `Attribute` yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Motjaba Hosseni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5623035/mojtaba-hosseini) is right so far there is nothing that resembles NSAttributedString in SwiftUI.
This should solve your problem for the time being:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("By tapping Done, you agree to the ")
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Button("privacy policy") {}
                Text(" and ")
                Button("terms of service") {}
                Text(".")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work as long as the first Text() isn't longer than a single line.

Comment: You can now use `Link("Stackoverflow", destination: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!)` in iOS 14 and Xcode 12.

Comment: Why is this the answer to the question? This does not address "how to use attributed string to embed links in text in swift ui" (paraphrasing). Meanwhile this post has been viewed over 7k times, and the answer is the comment above this one with 0 upvotes

Comment: Readability Issues when you increase the  Accessibility font size.  "privacy policy" becomes  "privacy ..." in the middle of the sentence.

Answer (score 95):

## iOS 15+ (Swift 5.5 +)

SwiftUI has built-in support for rendering Markdown

To create a link, enclose the link's text in brackets (e.g., [Duck Duck Go]) and then follow it immediately with the URL in parentheses (e.g., (https://duckduckgo.com)).

```
 Text("[Privacy Policy](https://example.com)")
```

https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/#links

#### String variable

1. Use `init(_ value: String)`

> Creates a localized string key from the given string value.

```
let link = "[Duck Duck Go](https://duckduckgo.com)"
Text(.init(link))
```

#### String interpolation

1. Use `init(_ value: String)`

> Creates a localized string key from the given string value.

```
  let url = "https://duckduckgo.com"
  let link = "[Duck Duck Go](\(url))"
  Text(.init(link))
```

#### Attributed text

2. Use `init(_ attributedContent: AttributedString)`

> Creates a text view that displays styled attributed content.

```
let markdownLink = try! AttributedString(markdown: "[Duck Duck Go](https://duckduckgo.com)")
Text(markdownLink)
```

*Similar question:
[Making parts of text bold in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61671313/making-parts-of-text-bold-in-swiftui/67922456#67922456)*

---

## Use the Link View

> A control for navigating to a URL.

```
Link("Privacy Policy", destination: URL(string: "https://example.com")!)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link

Comment: fantastic, this really helped me for iOS 15!

Comment: `let str = "[Privacy Policy](https://example.com)" Text(str) // does not work.`

Comment: When using iOS 15+, using the [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/link) element would probably be safer (and nicer). Example: `Link("Privacy Policy", destination: URL(string: "https://example.com")!)`

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. Agree and updated my answer. But they want to embede link in text.

Comment: @mahan The issue here is we can't change the foreground colour. It remains blue even after adding foregroundColor property to Text

Comment: @Pritish try this for single text - Text(.init("[Link Example](https://www.google.es/)"))
    .accentColor(.red)

Comment: You might have to use `.init` for a string literal with interpolations, e.g. `Text(.init("[link text](\(url))"))`.

Comment: For those just interested in making plain urls clickable, don't lose your time trying to replace occurrences of all url's within your string with `[link](link)`like I just did. 
`Text(.init(string))` works like a charm without going through that hassle.

Answer (score 32):

Just as @mahan mention, this works perfectly for **iOS 15.0** and above by using markdown language:

```
Text("[Privacy Policy](https://example.com)")
```

But if you're using a `String` variable, and put it into the `Text` it wouldn't work. Example:

```
let privacyPolicyText = "Read our [Privacy Policy](https://example.com) here."
Text(privacyPolicyText) // Will not work
```

### Solution for using a String variable

The reason is that `Text` got multiple initiations. So how do we solve this? The easiest way is just to do:

```
let privacyPolicyText = "Read our [Privacy Policy](https://example.com) here."
Text(.init(privacyPolicyText))
```

Result: Read our [Privacy Policy](https://example.com) here.

Comment: Link("Privacy Policy", destination: URL(string: "https://example.com")!) @jacobAhlberg

Comment: @Pritish this works, but it's another component. This won't work if you want to have the hyperlink in the middle of the `Text` component. For instance: "Click [here]({Your Link}) if you want to read more".

Comment: @JacobAhlberg is there a way to change link color?

Comment: @esp Just use the `viewModifier` called `.accentColor`.

Comment: I would suggest: `let privacyPolicyText = AttributedString("Read our [Privacy Policy](https://example.com) here.")`

Comment: how to use different color for link text?

Comment: @SunilTarge you can use `AttributedString(markdown:)` and setup custom Theme for your `Runs`. You can learn more at: https://www.kodeco.com/29501177-attributedstring-tutorial-for-swift-getting-started

Answer (score 25):

it's very simple just use LocalizedStringKey for example:

```
let message = "Hello, www.google.com this is just testing for hyperlinks, check this out our website https://www.apple.in thank you."

Text(LocalizedStringKey(message))
```

Comment: Are you aware that you can [edit] posts? I ask because it looks like you deleted a similar post and then created this one.

Comment: This is what I have been searching for! Thank you

Answer (score 8):

To be on the safe side, if your text is not a string literal, you will probably want to use `.init`. In other words, if there's any string concatenation, interpolation, etc., you may want to use `Text(.init(...))`.

Just note that `.init` in this case actually refers to `LocalizedStringKey.init`, so localization will still be happening, just like when you're just passing a string literal.

Here are some examples and their rendered output in Xcode 14 previews.

```swift
let foo = "Foo"
let bar = "Bar"
let link = "link"

Group {
  Text("Foo [Bar](link) Baz") // ✅
  Text("Foo" + " [Bar](link) Baz") // ❌
  Text(foo + " [Bar](link) Baz") // ❌
  Text("\(foo) [Bar](link) Baz") // ✅
  Text("\(foo) [Bar](\(link)) Baz") // ❌
  Text("\(foo) [\(bar)](\(link)) Baz") // ❌
}

Rectangle().height(1)

Group {
  Text(.init("Foo [Bar](link) Baz")) // ✅
  Text(.init("Foo" + " [Bar](link) Baz")) // ✅
  Text(.init(foo + " [Bar](link) Baz")) // ✅
  Text(.init("\(foo) [Bar](link) Baz")) // ✅
  Text(.init("\(foo) [Bar](\(link)) Baz")) // ✅
  Text(.init("\(foo) [\(bar)](\(link)) Baz")) // ✅
}
```

[image: Rendered output]

Comment: are these link tappable ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri It's been a while since I did this, but I would expect them to be tappable! If they're not, please let us know :)

Comment: no they are not by default, we have to add openURL modifier to those texts or group, to allow opening the urls

Answer (score 5):

**I tried concatenated Texts with Link in between and these are the ways for iOS 15+ and below iOS 15.**

```
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        
        Text("[Seperate Link 1 ](https://www.android.com/intl/en_in/)")
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
        // green color is not applied.

        Text("[Seperate Link 2 ](https://www.apple.com/in/)")
            .font(.caption)
            .accentColor(Color.green)
        // green is applied.
        
        Text("By authorizing you agree our ")
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        + Text("[Terms and Conditions](https://www.android.com/intl/en_in/)")
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(Color.green) // default blue is applied
        + Text(" and ")
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        + Text("[Privacy Policy](https://www.apple.com/in/)")
            .font(.caption)
            .foregroundColor(Color.green) // default blue
        // cannot use accentColor(Color.green) here
    }
    else{
        // lower iOS versions.
        VStack{
            Text("By authorizing you agree our ")
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            
            HStack(spacing: 4 ) {
                Text("Terms and Conditions")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        let url = URL.init(string: "https://www.android.com/intl/en_in/")
                        guard let termsAndConditionURL = url, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(termsAndConditionURL) else { return }
                        UIApplication.shared.open(termsAndConditionURL)
                    }
                Text("and")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                Text("Privacy Policy")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        let url = URL.init(string: "https://www.apple.com/in/")
                        guard let privacyPolicyURL = url, UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(privacyPolicyURL) else { return }
                        UIApplication.shared.open(privacyPolicyURL)
                    }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

[swift](/questions/tagged/swift)  [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)  [swiftui](/questions/tagged/swiftui)

Answer (score 4):

Hyperlink

Hypelink color

Bold text

Underline hyperlink Color

```
        Text("By tapping Done, you agree to the [privacy policy](https://www..) and [Terms and Conditions](https://www.terms.)")
             .padding()
         
         Text("By tapping Done, you agree to the \(Text("[privacy policy](https://www.)")) and \(Text("[Terms and Conditions](https://www.)"))")
             .accentColor(.red)
             .padding()
         
         Text("**By tapping Done:** you agree to the \(Text("[privacy policy](https://www.)")) and \(Text("[Terms and Conditions](https://www.)"))")
             .padding()
         
         Text("By tapping Done, you agree to the \(Text("[privacy policy](https://www.)").underline()) and \(Text("[Terms and Conditions](https://www.)").underline())")
             .accentColor(.red)
             .padding()
         
         Text("By tapping Done, you agree to the \(Text("[privacy policy](https://www.)").underline()) and \(Text("[Terms and Conditions](https://www.)").underline())")
             .padding()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way also. I think this is simplest form solution.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(getAttriText())
    }
    .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction(handler: { url in
      if url.absoluteString.contains("privacy") {
        // action
      }
      
      if url.absoluteString.contains("terms") {
        // action
      }
      return .systemAction // change if you want to discard action
    }))
  }
  
  func getAttriText() -> AttributedString {
    
    var attriString = AttributedString("By tapping Done, you agree to the privacy policy and terms of service")
    attriString.foregroundColor = .black
    
    if let privacyRange = attriString.range(of: "privacy policy") {
      attriString[privacyRange].link = URL(string: "www.apple.com/privacy")
      attriString[privacyRange].underlineStyle = .single
      attriString[privacyRange].foregroundColor = .blue
    }
    
    if let termsRange = attriString.range(of: "terms of service") {
      attriString[termsRange].link = URL(string: "www.apple.com/terms")
      attriString[termsRange].underlineStyle = .single
      attriString[termsRange].foregroundColor = .blue
    }
    
    return attriString
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's always an option to wrap a UIKit view in `UIViewRepresentable`. Just have to go through the manual process of exposing each attribute you want to change.

```swift
struct AttributedText: UIViewRepresentable {
    var attributedText: NSAttributedString

    init(_ attributedText: NSAttributedString) {
        self.attributedText = attributedText
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        return UITextView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ label: UITextView, context: Context) {
        label.attributedText = attributedText
    }
}

//usage: AttributedText(NSAttributedString())
```

Comment: A big limitation of this approach seems to be that UIViewRepresentable does not communicate the intrinsicContentSize of the UITextView up to SwiftUI - AttributedText will take up all the space available to it, which plays havoc with StackViews etc

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late but I solved the same problem using HTML.
First I created a small helper and link model.

```
struct HTMLStringView: UIViewRepresentable {
  let htmlContent: String

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
    return WKWebView()
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
    uiView.loadHTMLString(htmlContent, baseURL: nil)
  }
}

struct TextLink {
    let url: URL
    let title: String
}
```

Next I created function that changes String to HTML and replaces first occurrence of @link to my tappable link.

```
var content = "My string with @link."
var link = TextLink(url: URL(string: "https://www.facebook.com")!, title: "Facebook")
var body: some View {
    let bodySize = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body).pointSize
    var html = "<span style=\"font: -apple-system-body; font-size:calc(\(bodySize)px + 1.0vw)\">"

    if let linkRange = content.range(of: "@link") {
        let startText = content[content.startIndex ..< linkRange.lowerBound]
        let endText = content[linkRange.upperBound ..< content.endIndex]
        html += startText
        html += "<a href=\"\(link.url.absoluteString)\">\(link.title)</a>"
        html += endText
    } else {
        html += content
    }
    
    html += "</span>"
    
    return HTMLStringView(htmlContent: html)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*** **iOS 15** ***

You can add emails or phonenumbers like this too:

```
    var infoText = "For any queries reach out to [email] or call [phone]"
    var phone = "+45 12345678".replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    var email = "some-email@some-host.something"
    
    var footerText: String {
        return infoText
            .replacingOccurrences(
                of: "[email]",
                with: "[\(email)](mailto:\(email))"
            )
            .replacingOccurrences(
                of: "[phone]",
                with: "[\(phone)](tel:\(phone))"
            )
    }
```

```
Text(.init(footerText))
```

Just remember the links (phone mainly, as emails doesn't have spaces) can't have spaces.

Also remember that this won't work on the simulator. You need a real device to test it.

Answer (score 1):

#### iOS 15 below

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUIFlowLayout

public struct HyperlinkText: View {
    private let subStrings: [StringWithLinks]
    
    public init(html: String) {
        let newString = html.replacingOccurrences(of: "<a href=\'(.+)\'>(.+)</a>",
                                                          with: "@&@$2#&#$1@&@",
                                                          options: .regularExpression,
                                                          range: nil)
        self.subStrings = newString.components(separatedBy: "@&@").compactMap{ subString in
            let arr = subString.components(separatedBy: "#&#")
            return StringWithLinks(string: arr[0], link: arr[safe: 1])
        }
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        FlowLayout(mode: .scrollable,
                   binding: .constant(false),
                   items: subStrings,
                   itemSpacing: 0) { subString in
            if let link = subString.link, let url = URL(string: link) {
                Text(subString.string)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(hexString: "#FF0000EE"))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                        }
                    }
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            } else {
                Text(subString.string).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StringWithLinks: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let string: String
    let link: String?
    
    static func == (lhs: StringWithLinks, rhs: StringWithLinks) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to effectively do this, is to use `.environment` which gives you control over what happens when the user taps a link within the text. For instance, you may want to open the url within a webview inside the app, rather than open in the device browser.

```
@State private var isPresentedPrivacyPolicy = false
@State private var isPresentedTermsOfUse = false

private let privacyPolicyURL = "https://privacypolicy.com"
private let termsOfUseURL = "https://termsofuse.com"

HStack{
    let privacyPolicyText = "By continuing you accept our [Privacy Policy](\(privacyPolicyURL)) and [Terms of Use](\(termsOfUseURL))."
    Text(privacyPolicyText)
    .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
        if url.absoluteString == privacyPolicyURL {
            isPresentedPrivacyPolicy.toggle()
        } else if url.absoluteString == termsOfUseURL {
            isPresentedTermsOfUse.toggle()
        }
        return .handled
    })
}
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresentedPrivacyPolicy) {
    NavigationStack {
        WebView(url: URL(string: privacyPolicyURL)!) 
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .navigationTitle("Privacy Policy")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
.sheet(isPresented: $isPresentedTermsOfUse) {
    NavigationStack {
        WebView(url: URL(string: termsOfUseURL)!)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .navigationTitle("Terms of Use")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
```

And WebView:

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -10):

Use built-in function `+`, it looks like a charm:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {

            }) {
                Text("By tapping Done, you agree to the ")
              + Text("privacy policy")
                  .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
              + Text(" and ")
              + Text("terms of service")
                  .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
              + Text(".")
            }
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes the entire text clickable, not just the link part. And in this case, there are 2 links and there is no way to differentiate which one was clicked.