# NavigationLink inline with Text View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

I have some larger text, and it basically should look like this:

[image]

This bold part of text should be NavigationLink.

I tried with HStack, and all simple solutions, but it won't work.
Is it maybe some library, or anything to make this simple to do.
Sure, you can answer me the more complicated solution, there is no problem, but I would prefer some easier way to do this.

Comment: It can't be done, it has to use markdown in combination with `openURL`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listen to link click in SwiftUI TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75192976/listen-to-link-click-in-swiftui-textview)

Comment: It doesn't help me, but thanks for answer.

Comment: It is the effect that I want to achieve, but can't send NavigatioLink

Comment: Maybe this is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744392/how-to-make-hyperlinks-in-swiftui

Comment: This is just for hyperlinks that leads to outside websites... I need  when this bold words are tapped to show op my ContetView() for example.

Comment: You can present navigation links programmatically with that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Markdown Text, a custom url scheme, and `.onOpenUrl` modifier:

```
struct ContentView: View {
 
    let text1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin imperdiet ipsum purus, sit amet mollis nunc "
    let text2 = "bibendum eget."
    let text3 = " Nulla suscipit mauris non diam varius sagittis. Ut feugiat imperdiet bibendum. Vestibulum dui quam, bibendum sit amet imperdiet sit amet, dapibus sit amet mauris."
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                Text(text1) +
                Text("[\(text2)](myappurl://action)").bold() +
                Text(text3)
            }
            .padding()
            .onOpenURL { url in
                path.append(1)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Main")
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { value in
                Text(value, format: .number)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75112555/123632) for full details on how to configure the url scheme.

[image]