# how to text.append() a Hyperlink to TextEditor Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, hyperlink, append, swiftui-texteditor

I have a TextEditor that i want to add a clickable Hyperlink using the TextEditor text.append()

```
TextEditor(text: $textE)
                    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
```

```
textE.append(contentsOf: "\n" + LINK......)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use markdown to achieve hyperlink in text.

```
Text("Hello! Example of a markdown with a link [example](https://example.com)")
```

[This question may be useful for you about how to use uitextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238366/uitextview-with-hyperlink-text)

Comment: Error: Instance method 'append(contentsOf:)' requires that 'Text' conform to 'Sequence'

Comment: textE.append(contentsOf: Text("Hello! Example of a markdown with a link [example](https://example.com)"))

Comment: Um in this case, I just did something similar in swiftui. What I was trying to do is to add some hyperlink in between some normal text. It seems like swiftui doesn't have a very good way to achieve this. So I implement the UITextView from uikit. I added a link above, you can check it out.